# seek to a point in html5 video

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, seek

Is it possible to seek to a particular point in `html5 video` displayed in a web page? I mean ,can I  input a particular time value (say `01:20:30:045` ) and have the player control (slider) move to that point and play from that point onwards?

In older version of mozilla `vlcplugin` I think this is possible by `seek(seconds,is_relative)` method..but I would like to know if this is possible in html video.

**Edit:**

I created the page with video and added javascript as below.When I click on the link ,it displays the time of click..but it doesn't increment the play location..but continues to play normally.

Shouldn't the video play location get changed?

html

```
<video id="vid" width="640" height="360" controls>
       <source src="/myvid/test.mp4" type="video/mp4" /> 
</video>
<a id="gettime" href="#">time</a>
<p>
you clicked at:<span id="showtime"> </span> 
</p>
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var player = $('#vid').get(0);
    $('#gettime').click(function(){
            if(player){
                current_time=player.currentTime;
                $('#showtime').html(current_time+" seconds");
                player.currentTime=current_time+10;
            }
        });
}
);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 video seeking \[updated\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311570/html5-video-seeking-updated)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can use `v.currentTime = seconds;` to seek to a given position.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime

Comment: The server also needs to include the following header in the response: "Accept-Ranges": "bytes"

Comment: this is not working on a few videos around 4MB. any thoughts?

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately it seems with some movie elements it behaves differently than others.  For instance with an amazon video_element, it seems you must call pause before you can seek anywhere, then call play.  However, if you call play "too quickly" after setting the `currentTime` then it won't stick.  Odd.

Here is my current work around:

```
function seekToTime(ts) {
  // try and avoid pauses after seeking
  video_element.pause();
  video_element.currentTime = ts; // if this is far enough away from current, it implies a "play" call as well...oddly. I mean seriously that is junk.
    // however if it close enough, then we need to call play manually
    // some shenanigans to try and work around this:
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        if (video_element.paused && video_element.readyState ==4 || !video_element.paused) {
            video_element.play();
            clearInterval(timer);
        }       
    }, 50);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Top answer is outdated.

You can still use:

```
this.video.currentTime = 10 // seconds
```

But now you also have:

```
this.video.fastSeek(10) // seconds
```

The docs provide the following warnings regarding the `fastSeek` method:

> Experimental: This is an experimental technology
> Check the Browser compatibility table carefully before using this in production.
> The HTMLMediaElement.fastSeek() method quickly seeks the media to the new time with precision tradeoff.
> If you need to seek with precision, you should set HTMLMediaElement.currentTime instead.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/fastSeek

Based on the above I guess the following is best if cross browser compatibility and performance are your top priority:

```
const seek = secs => {
  if (this.video.fastSeek) {
    this.video.fastSeek(secs)
  } else {
    this.video.currentTime = secs
  }
}
seek(10)
```

If you prefer accuracy over performance then stick with:

```
this.video.currentTime = secs
```

At the time of writing `fastSeek` is only rolled out to Safari and Firefox but expect this to change. Check the compatibility table at the above link for the latest info on browser compatibility.

Comment: Not available in Chrome FYI