# How set html5 video to initial position after video is completed?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have used html5 video tag to for playing video.
Once the complete video is played, i want to set the video current time to zero.
If i use loop video will come to initial position and will be automatically played. I want to bring video to initial position but automatic playing is not required. How to achieve this?

Html is

```html
<div class="video-wrapper" id="my-video" >
    <video src="<?php echo asset_url().'videos/Video.mp4';?>" controlsList="nodownload" id="my-video"></video>
</div>
```

javascript is

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    /**
     * Video element
     * @type {HTMLElement}
    */
    var video = document.getElementById("my-video");

    /**
     * Check if video can play, and play it
    */
    video.addEventListener("canplay", function(){
        
      video.play();
    });
     
    
       


     

  });
```

Comment: Answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461669/seek-to-a-point-in-html5-video

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var video = document.getElementById("my-video");

    video.addEventListener("canplay", function(){
      video.play();
    });

    video.addEventListener("ended", function(){
      video.currentTime = 0;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a listener to the 'ended' event (reference here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) and in the handler set the video's currentTime to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onEnded event to check when the video ended and use the currentTime attribute to set the current time back to zero.

OnEnded event: [onended event](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_ended.asp)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    /**
     * Video element
     * @type {HTMLElement}
    */
    var video = document.getElementById("my-video");

    /**
     * Check if video can play, and play it
    */
    video.addEventListener("canplay", function(){   
      video.play();
    });


     video.addEventListener("ended", function(){
      video.currentTime = 0;
    });
};
    
       


     

  });
```