# HTML 5 Video seek/chapters

Tags: html, video, html5-video

I've got a long .m4v video file (~ 1 hour) on my server,but I want to show a video on my site (HTML-5 ) that only show's subsections of it (e.g minutes 3 -> 5 followed by minutes 19 -> 20). So the video my users see is only 5 mins long.

Is anyone aware of any current HTML-5 video players or clever tricks that would support this use case ? I guess the functionality I want is like the quicktime reference file, but in HTML5 -video so that if my users play the video through they only see the 'sub-sections' and nothing in between.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can't you simply chop off the portions you want and create a file and show only those minutes? Else your player must do the seek when it reaches a particular point. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311570/html5-video-seeking-updated if it helps

Comment: Thanks! .. yea I want to avoid making new smaller seperate video files (as there will be many instances of these and I want to be able to re-configure) .. the seekToTime function is closer to what I'm after. Would be be great if there was a player that I could provide the time's to as metadata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Media Fragments URIs](http://www.w3.org/TR/media-frags/) to tell the browser to only request a portion of the video file from the server.

For example, to retrieve this video from 10 seconds to 20 seconds, set your video source(s) using a url like this:

```
<video src="myvideo.webm#t=10,20"></video>
```

As usual, this will not work in Internet Explorer.

You'll still need to stitch the multiple video fragments together in order. You can put an "ended" event listener on each one to queue up the next video, or you can use a library like [popcorn.sequence](https://github.com/rwldrn/popcorn.sequence)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with brianchirls. Media fragments work great and it's so little code!

Another option is to use the awesome built-in listeners for the HTML5 video tag.

You can do something like the following:

```
video = document.getElementByTagName('video')[0];
insAndOuts = [{in: 3, out: 5}, {in: 19, out: 20}];

video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function(){
  video.currentTime = insAndOuts[0].in;
});

var nextTime = function(time){
  var ends = _.map(insAndOuts, function(x){ return x.out});
  return ends.indexOf(time) + 1;
};

video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(){
  var nextIndex = nextTime(video.currentTime)
  if(nextIndex > 0) {
    video.currentTime = insAndOuts[nextIndex].in;
  }
});
```

To the best of my recollection this is basically what that popcorn sequence thing from brianchirls' post. This will work on all browsers, but it's a lot of code to manage.