# How to check if user is seeking with HTML5 video with JQuery

Tags: jquery, video, html5-video

I've tried:

```
$("#test").seek;
$("#test").seeking;
$("#test").seek();
$("#test").seeking();
```

What am I doing wrong? I need to be able to check if the user is seeking with my video using JQuery. Thanks...

Comment: Take a look there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311570/html5-video-seeking-updated

Comment: This talks about $("#test").currentTime. Basically, is there no seek command for JQuery? Do I need to program the function by checking if currentTime is different from before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need jQuery to do this, you can do it with regular JS.

```
var vid = document.getElementById('video');

vid.onseeking = function() {
  console.log(vid.seeking);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cppye8p2/

Comment: Note that this also fires if the video is seeking due to the player deciding that seeking should be performed. So you may get false positives.